# Kolmisoft login / registration issue

Tags: android, ios, registration, kolmisoft, portsip

I am using Kolimisoft server for VOIP calls in my mobile application. I was able to register user with Kolmisoft server and getting this response:

```
<status>
    <success>Registration successful</success>
</status>
<user_device_settings>
    <email>Registration email</email> - If email sending enabled.
    <user_id> user id</user_id> 
    <device_type> device type [SIP|IAX2]</device_type>
    <device_id> device id </device_id> 
    <username> device username </username>
    <password> device password </password>
    <pin> device pin </pin>
    <server_ip> Asterisk Server IP </server_ip>
    <registration_notice> Registration notice which is set in Settings </registration_notice>
 </user_device_settings>
```

After getting this response, I was passing device username and device password to PortSIP SDK for SDK registration process and getting success callback.

Once user Logged-Out from app and tried to logged-In again to PortSIP SDK, I was getting forbidden request (status code 403, unauthorised user). I tried to debug my code and got SDK does not understand entered username and password. SDK knows only device username and device password.

I tried to call user_login API of Kolmisoft server, but it gives me only user_id. How I can get device username and device password, so that, user will be able to authenticate in SDK with that credentials.

Please let me know, is there any single API to associate device username and device password or how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

These APIs can return device Username and Password:
http://wiki.kolmisoft.com/index.php/MOR_API_devices_get
http://wiki.kolmisoft.com/index.php/MOR_API_device_details_get

Also, Kolmisoft support should help you with similar questions.